# Git: How do I return to the branch after fixing merge conflicts?

Tags: git

Sometimes I will get a merge conflict when I `git merge`. I'll get the error:

> Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

That's fine, and I fix the conflicts.

The problem is, once this happens, I seem to get kicked out of the branch I'm working on. Doing a `git branch` just shows me as on the `develop` branch.

If I try to check out the branch I was just working on I get an error

> Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.

If I try to commit or stash I get the error:

> You are not on the correct branch.

The only way I can break out of this is to use `git reset --hard HEAD` which of course means I loose all my work.

Would anyone know why this is happening and what I can do?

Comment: After fixing the merge conflict, you should conclude the merge with `git commit` (like `git status` tells you to). After that you are automatically returned to the branch you were working on.

Answer (score 0):

1. `git status` to check your now status.
2. `git diff` to confirm that you fix conflicts correctly.
3. `git add` your files.
4. `git commit`.

   do your other jobs...

Answer (score 0):

> The only way I can break out of this is to use git reset --hard HEAD which of course means I loose all my work.

You're doing it wrong: use `git merge --abort` or `git reset --merge` if you want quit the current merge in progress.

Or finish the current merge as described by kagv. There is no third option... git has encountered a conflict and requires you to solve it manually. So fix it or reset to stable.

Note: when git detects a conflict (during a merge, rebase or cherry-pick action) you end up in such a special mode with limited functionality (such as preventing you from checking out a different revision...).